# How to change the App signature?

Tags: android, ios, codenameone, signature

I have a released android/ios app.  I would like to keep the
released version around on my devices as a reference, while I 
continue development and make experimental builds.

I've cloned the project, but can't seem to change the app signature
so builds don't overwrite the released version.  What do I need to 
change so I can have parallel versions?

Comment: You can't have the same package name, in regards to Android. Gradle flavors along with some sort of repository could help with this.

Answer (score 1):

In case of iOS you have to change the "bundle ID" in info.plist. The same thing represented as "App ID" (Project Properties -> Categories -> Codename One -> iOS) in codenameone

Comment: Codename One also relies on the main package == app id so you need to make sure the package is updated everywhere within the codenameone_settings.properties.